# Can't run Chrome browser with custom profile selenium

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying start selenium tests in chrome browser with my custom Profile which contains necessary cookies.
I use Chrome 57 and chromedriver 2.29
My code is :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=/Users/tester/Desktop/ChromeProf/QAChromeProfile");
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors","disable-infobars","enable-automation","--window-size=375,667");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

It works fine, but don't use my chrome profile. Help me, pls...)

Comment: Can you elaborate how are you trying to access the new Chrome profile?

Comment: I resolve my problem. Thx.

Comment: @PanamaBoy what was the issue?

Comment: Can you please share how did you solved your issue?

Answer (score 5):

Don't include the profile directory in the `user-data-dir` argument. When using `user-data-dir` option with any profile besides the default, i've had to also use the `profile-dir` argument.

Make sure you change `user-data-dir` to your [Chrome User Data](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md) directory. Don't worry about spaces. Do not try to put quotes or to escape spaces in the argument value.

`Profile 1`

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")

driver = Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/path/to/chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

[Keep this in mind](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15311/adding-user-data-dir-option-to-chromedriver-makes-it-not-work-and-timeout-only) when running your code. (basically, close any open Chrome instances running before running selenium with custom Chrome profiles in use)